# Unicode - Extract chars in a String contains Tamil letters in Java

Tags: java, unicode-string

I am working to support unicode chars in the system, so I want to split chars in string that contains Tamil letters. I don't know to handle string in other than English in Java.

```
String word = new String("தமிழ்")
String[] chars = word.split("")
```

### What was output

[த, ம, ி, ழ, ்]

### What is expected

[த, மி, ழ்]

Answer (score 0):

The String assigned to "word" is in fact 5 Unicode characters. The 3rd character, for example (U+0BFF) combines with the preceding one (U+0BAE?) to make one displayed symbol.

Since you're splitting the word into characters, 5 characters is what you'll get.  There is no such single character as (for example) the middle symbol displayed in your original string.

Due to *combining characters*, the apparent number of symbols displayed on-screen is not necessarily the same as the number of Unicode characters. In general, programs that render Unicode strings have to be cognizant of combining characters.

See [this document](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch12.pdf#G10162) for issues of Tamil in Unicode. Figure 12-21 discusses the i vowel sound, which is the middle character of the 5.

It's not clear what your purpose is in splitting the string. If you really want "apparent symbols" (I'm making up this term) then you'll presumably need to scan the resulting characters to look for combining characters.

[This document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/char.html) describes one approach that seems like it would work for you, though the page says there are better facilities in  releases after JDK 8, which I did not take the time to look for.  Still, this may illuminate what's going on a little more thoroughly.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem that it shows 5 chars. I used REGEX to parse/split/process the string which contains Tamil letters

Comment: Wrong tool for the job, then? ```split``` deals in Unicode characters, not what I clumsily called "apparent symbols". It's possible you could write a more complicated regex that handles units of *character followed by some number of combining characters* but that is not then a use of ```split```, and the ```BreakIterator``` solution looks more attractive to me.

Comment: You could try splitting on the regex ```(?U)(?!\p{Mc})``` but I'm far from confident about that, particularly the ```Mc``` part.  You might also have to set the locale first.